# Access Shape object in PowerPoint via Office.js

Tags: javascript, powerpoint, office365

I am looking for a solution to iterate over all shapes in a PowerPoint slide (during a presentation) and find the position and size of all shapes that include a hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

At the present point this is not possible.

The only way to interact with data on the slides is the function document.getSelectedDataAsync(). I guess if you could get the user to select all data on the slide then you could access it with the getSelectedDataAsync function. However, if you take a look at the supported Office.CoercionType then you will find that PowerPoint Add-Ins only support Text and SlideRange.

For reference look at the [Official Documentation for Document.getSelectedDataAsync](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getselecteddataasync)

Anyhow, you can suggest further functionality [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Cheers mate.

Comment: I cannot post more than 2 links yet.. so here you go..Maybe you should have a look at this similiar suggestion 
https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/11161365-getselecteddataasync-for-powerpoint-shapes